# PHP SOAPCall Input is null

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Service
>   operation Pickup_Cancel failed due to validation errors: Input is null

**Here's my code:**

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://etrack.postaplus.net/APIService/PostaWebClient.svc?singleWsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));

$params = array(
        "CodeStation" => `BEY`,
        "PickupNumber" => `1`,
        "Reason" => `test reason`,
        "Password" => `sss`,
        "ShipperAccount" => `acc`,
        "UserName" => `acc`,
    );

$client->Pickup_Cancel($params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awnser to the question you didn't ask is probably: replace the backticks (`) by singlequotes (')

-- Edit. That was not the problem.

Here is the case. SOAP can be a pain to get going. My experience is to use a good soap class or just non-wsdl mode. Read up on this in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

So don't do this:

```
$return = $soapClient->functionName($data);
```

But this:

```
$return = $soapClient->__SoapCall('functionName', $data);
```

Also get a grip on what the server wants, load the WSDL url into a client like SoapUI https://www.soapui.org/ (its free). This lets you check if the SoapServer works and how you should approach it with your call.

In your case the WSDL states this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:pos="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PostaWebClient">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Pickup_Cancel>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:CLIENTINFO>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:CodeStation>asd</pos:CodeStation>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:Password>asd</pos:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:ShipperAccount>asd</pos:ShipperAccount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:UserName>asd</pos:UserName>
         </tem:CLIENTINFO>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:PickupNumber>asd</tem:PickupNumber>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Reason>asd</tem:Reason>
      </tem:Pickup_Cancel>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which translates to this PHP code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://etrack.postaplus.net/APIService/PostaWebClient.svc?singleWsdl");

$params = [
    'Pickup_Cancel' => [
        'CLIENTINFO' => [
            'Password' => 'sss',
            'ShipperAccount' => 'acc',
            'UserName' => 'acc',
            'CodeStation' => '',
        ],
        'PickupNumber' => '',
        'Reason' => '',
    ],
];

$client->__SoapCall("Pickup_Cancel", $params);
```

See how the array matches the WSDL xml format?

This should also give you the feedback you need to proceed. If not, its probably time to get 'real' help :) Goodluck.

Comment: @AhmedSaeed well it was a guess and you still havent asked a real question.  Perhaps you could provide some more info and a link to the documentation?

Comment: link of documentation is https://etrack.postaplus.net/CustomerPortal/Documentation/CUSTAPI.pdf?enc=E6xJlrJcFydp7%2bIqArRr3A%3d%3d 

Do you need any extra info?